# DataBinding Between a WPF GUI and a couple of ListBox/CheckBox

Tags: wpf, binding, listbox, checkbox, datacontext

The thing i want to do looks easy, but takes me a lot of time without any result.. =/
I'd like to have a WPF window which takes an object with some proprieties and used it to popolate a couple of item.
In the specific the object recieved is so defined:

```
public class ParameterForGraphicOptions
{
    public List<VariablesOptions> Variables { get; set; }
    public List<string> Simulations { get; set; }
    public List<string> ShowSimulations { get; set; }
}
public class VariablesOptions
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Show { get; set; }
    public bool Average { get; set; }
    public bool Var { get; set; }
}
```

And i'd like to populate 2 ListBox with Simulations and ShowSimulations, and also have another list which is connected to Variables Name and 3 check box which change their values when you change the selected item in the list.. The Windows code (.cs) follows:

```
public GraphicOptions(ParameterForGraphicOptions pfgo) //NAME OF THE WINDOW
{
    InitializeComponent();                     //STD CALL
    this.DataContext = pfgo;                   //CONNECTING THE DATA CONTEXT
}
```

The XAML code for binding is this:

```
<Window x:Class="GUI.GraphicOptions"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="GraphicOptions" Height="450" Width="350">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="25" />
            <RowDefinition Height="150"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="25" />
            <RowDefinition Height="150"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="25" />
            <RowDefinition Height="11*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0">Simulation in Progress</Label>
        <Label Margin="188,0,0,0">Simulation to Show</Label>
        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="Simulations" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140" />  
        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="188,0,0,0" Name="SimulationsToShow" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140" />
        <Label Grid.Row="2">Variables to Show</Label>

        <ListBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" DataContext="{Binding Variables.Name}" Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="Variables" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140"  Grid.RowSpan="2" />
        <CheckBox Grid.Row="3" Content="Show" IsChecked="{Binding Variables.Show}"  Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="Show" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" Margin="163,5,0,0" />
        <CheckBox Grid.Row="3" Content="Average" IsChecked="{Binding Variables.Average}"  Height="25"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="Average" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" Margin="174,54,0,0" Checked="Average_Checked" />
        <CheckBox Grid.Row="3" Content="Var" IsChecked="{Binding Variables.Var}" Height="25"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="Variance" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" Margin="163,31,0,0" />
        <CheckBox Content="Refresh Graphic During Computation" Grid.Row="5" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="Continuos" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="220" />
        <Button Content="Save" Grid.Row="5" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="253,1,0,0" Name="Save" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Save_Click" />
        <Button Content="->" Grid.Row="1" Height="35" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="145,30,0,0" Name="OneSimulation" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="35" />
        <Button Content="=>" Grid.Row="1" Height="35" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="145,65,0,0" Name="AllSimulation" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="35" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I tried in many ways, but always bind only a item, so I can't understand HOW this library works..
Many thanks 4 all :P

The question is: is there any wrong thing in the code i posted?

P.S.: Sorry for my English :P

Comment: Please rephrase your question , its really hard to understnad what you want to ask?

Comment: I would suggest you to read at least one tutorial about WPF data binding. http://coredotnet.blogspot.com/2006/05/wpf-data-binding-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bind a single control with plural items. Bind with a single selected item.

Here is a correct solution:

```
<ListBox x:Name="vars" ItemsSource="{Binding Variables}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding SelectedItem.Show, ElementName=vars, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding SelectedItem.Average, ElementName=vars, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding SelectedItem.Var, ElementName=vars, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now i'll try to fix my problem ^^"